# Why won't my array reverse?

Tags: php

[image: php code snippet here]

```
<?php
  $messages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM privatemessages WHERE nodeview='$_GET[nodeview]' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5 OFFSET $_GET[offset]");
  while($message = mysql_fetch_array( $messages )) {
  $user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$message[senderuserid]' ");
  $user = mysql_fetch_array($user);
  $rows[] = $message[message];


  }
  print_r($rows);
  array_reverse($rows);
  print_r($rows);

  ?>
```

Why does it reverse some arrays but not others?

Comment: Please post your code as text, formatted to a code block, rather than as an image. Likewise, post your output sample as text.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: My webhost uses mod_security so I'm not vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. I will use an ORM such as TBSsql or Medoo once the php upgrade breaks my scripts.

Comment: mod_security is a blacklist. It covers known and a few generic exploits. But its ruleset is by no means clever enough to prevent all kinds of data tampering and code injections.

Comment: I tried to sql injection my own website that I coded and it gave me a 406 Not Acceptable error when I tried to, so I suppose that my web host is protected against sql injection.

Answer (score 7):

> array_reverse — Return an array with elements in reverse order

It returns the reversed array, but does not reverse it "in place"

```
$rows = array_reverse($rows);
```

Comment: Plus, `mysql_` functions family is **deprecated**.. Please do migrate..